# Error handling from DoAction Custom Actions

Tags: wix

I am trying to use an error dialog from a DoAction CustomAction. I know I cannot use `MsiProcessMessage`, at the moment I am using a `MessageBox`but I know this is not recommended. Can anyone tell me how to use the error table from a DoAction CustomAction?

What I want to do is check if a number is greater than 10,000 and if it is throw an error:

```
    WcaGetIntProperty(L"DIAGNOSTICCHANNELS",&szDiagnosticChannels);
    if (szDiagnosticChannels > 10000) MessageBox(NULL, szError, szTitle, MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
```

Comment: Looks like you are doing a GetProperty to retreve the value of a property and want to show an error if it's too large. What about scheduling a custom action type 19 just before your customaction using a condition based on the value of the DiagnosticChannels(?)property to show an error and quit? That way you don't have to show the error inside your CA.

Comment: @StephenConnolly That's an excellent idea - that will work for some of my custom actions but I have others that it will not work for as I have to check if there is only letters, etc. Thanks Also is there any way that it could only be a warning?

Comment: Type 19 is error only. If you wanted a warning you would need to write a CA to handle that. Unfortunately there are issues with using ProcessMessage() to show message boxes on the client side e.g. in a wizard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very frustrating that the Windows Installer doesn't support MsiProcessMessage() from a DoAction. Fortunately, the wcautil.lib in the WiX toolset has some helper methods that will make it not too hard to replicate. It'd look a lot like this:

```
int nDiagnosticChannels = 0;
PMSIHANDLE hErrorTable;
PMSIHANDLE hErrorMessage;
LPWSTR sczError = NULL;
LPWSTR sczErrorFormatted = NULL;

hr = WcaGetIntProperty(L"DIAGNOSTICCHANNELS",&nDiagnosticChannels);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to read DIAGNOSTICCHANNELS property.");

if (nDiagnosticChannels > 10000)
{
    // "12345" is your custom error number.
    hr = WcaOpenExecuteView("SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error`=12345", &hErrorTable); 
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to query error table.");

    hr = WcaFetchSingleRecord(hErrorTable, hErrorMessage);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to get message from error table.");

    hr = WcaGetRecordString(hErrorMessage, 1, &sczError);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to get error message");

    hr = WcaGetFormattedString(sczError, &sczErrorFormatted);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to format error message");

    ::MessageBox(NULL, sczErrorFormatted, szTitle, MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}

LExit:
    ReleaseStr(sczError);
    ReleaseStr(sczErrorFormatted);
    return hr;
```

It'd be nice if there were a couple more helper functions there to cut down a few functions calls but it will work.

Comment: Rob, you have just made my whole life simple, Thank you very much..:)